# Install Ruby on Rails on Debian 6 (Apache)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, debian

I am trying to get Ruby on Rails working on my Debian 6.0.5 (Squeeze) with Apache (http://hosting.wedos.com/en/virtual/debian-isp.html). There is no Ruby now. It is running on VPS so I have all administrator rights. I have found few tutorials but they all seem to provide very different solutions and I can not make any mistakes, since many others websites are running on that server. I have been working only with PHP until now :/

Does anyone know a good working example/tutorial or could you suggest a solution?

Help very appretiated! I don't want to buy separate VPS just for trying RoR. I know it can be done localy on my machine (which I did and it works fine) but I need to see if I can actually use it for my live projects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rvm` (https://rvm.io/) to do this. It's the ruby version manager and it's actually managing all your different ruby versions and gems.

you can copy paste this to your bash and it will install ruby and rails for you:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install 2.2.1
gem install rails
```

This should work as long as you have curl and a gpg environment setup on your system.

// Also you maybe should learn a bit about rails. It comes with it own webserver so you don't need apache in the first place. Later you can use it as a server side proxy if you want...

// To install curl you can use:

```
apt-get install curl
```

Then you can retrun the commands listed above

Comment: Thanks! gpg is working, but there is no curl. I am just in the process of learning Rails :) Rails server is running on my localhost just fine, do you mean that I can do something of that kind on my server? I am a programmer but server management is not really my area... I am using ISPConfig for server management, which is quite a noob tool. So I am not really sure how to do any complex s**t using just ssh...